# How can I open a remote file over HTTP with Emacs?

Tags: http, emacs

Most of the open source software around expose its code over some HTTP service. I would like to open and browse such code from Emacs, but AFAICS tramp only allows for `ssh` and `ftp`.

My first question is thus how to open an HTTP URL for reading from within Emacs. Then, the possibly more advanced question is how to do that from the shell and `emacsclient`.

How would you do it?

Comment: Why not use your favourite browser and use the  `save page` option placing the HTML/CSS onto your local file system?

Comment: I can of course do it, but the lazy bastard in me will keep all that unused "garbage" forever. I would rather have my editor open the file for me, then trash it as soon as I'm done. I can already do `vim http://some/url`, but I'd rather stick to emacs.

Comment: @Ed Heal: I start to wander, do you really consider manual actions with lousy schedules as a better option over finding the proper command to invoke? :-)

Comment: Just thinking that it is better to just make a copy - use your local machine to update (presumably a live) web site and get it right on your machine before copying it across. Some operations are better done manually. As to lousy schedules - better learn time keeping. Comes in useful in other places.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Still, as a software developer I tend to believe that manual operations on software products is only necessary when automation fails. Besides, I can see myself needing this some million times in the next years, and those half a seconds I can spare really add up.

Comment: See also http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21180/is-there-a-way-to-show-open-a-file-from-a-uri-url

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `browse-url-emacs` <kbd>RET</kbd> `http...` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You might need to use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `normal-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> afterwards to set the appropriate mode for the buffer.

Comment: For Emacs 24, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632185/display-contents-of-remote-html-in-emacs

Answer (score 3):

There are two or three html viewers for emacs; I'd use [emacs-w3m](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/emacs-w3m). If you want to edit something remote via HTTP(S), perhaps Tramp's [`dav` external method](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#GVFS-based-methods) will work for you.