# How do I view a web-based file in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Say I've got two web based xml files that I would like to diff (test output vs. baseline). My current work-flow is to manually download the files to a temporary folder and load them into Emacs for diffing. I'm pretty sure there are better ways to do this but I'm stumped, especially as all the Emacs functions seem to open the URL in a browser,

Any solutions \ suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15318925/173715) suggests, `browse-url-emacs` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use `(url-handler-mode 1)` so you can visit a web page with `C-x C-f http://foo/bar RET`.

Comment: Thats awesome - very nice and pretty much exactly what I was looking for (I'd tried ffap).